# Android app not listed in Battery Usage

Tags: android, performance, battery

I was given a question and I have a hard time finding the correct answer.
Let's say that I have an app called MyApp and when this app is installed it drains the battery life really fast, I know that because when I uninstall the app the battery life is significantly improved.
When the app is installed I can't see it in the Android Build-in Battery Usage Stats in settings app which means that it's not the app that's draining the battery life.

What could be the problem?

I thought that the problem is that maybe the app is activating background services of Android, but was told that when I activate a service from an app, it is registered under the app's name and it should be listed in the battery usage.
I can't seem to find any information describing the problem I was given.

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Have you ever tried using the battery historian?

Comment: I don't need to use any tools for testing my battery usage because it's a general question I was asked.
I don't really have an app called MyApp. It's just a scenario of a "could happen" during development and I need to figured out what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yes I understood that, that's why I am saying: use the battery historian. If battery historian can't help you figure it out then nothing can.

Comment: Sorry to tell you but this is not what the guy who asked me was referring to. It's supposed to be something to do "sleep mode" and "wakelock"